# Mercurial: can't host on BitBucket.org with an error SSH, OpenSSH?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, bitbucket

For a new project :

1. I created a new repo inside the project's folder.
2. I created a new repo on bitbucket.org
3. Now I have one local repo and one remote repo. So I should not need to clone. I push from the local to remote.

In Repository Explorer, I fill the URL and "push outgoing changesets". No login and pwd asked? I get this error **error SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3**

---

Previously I cloned a HG project on bitbucket.org with no problem.
Is there any conflict with the previous repo? Where should I input the login and password?
I changed in the Global Settings > Proxy

```
Host : https://bitbucket.org/$myaccount
user :
password :
```

Should I use a proxy ? Still something wrong with **error SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3**

Comment: Are you trying to create a repository on bitbucket through the Mercurial client? That won't work, you have to go to the bitbucket website and create the repository first.

Comment: Nope I already created a repo on bitbucket. Through the Mercurial client, I want to push (by cloning) my local repo.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "push (by cloning)", Have you double-checked that you specify the right URL to your BitBucket repository when pushing?

Comment: I'm also assuming that when you write "$myaccount" and "$myrepo" in your question, that's just to hide that information from us, you're not actually trying to push using those texts exactly like that?

Comment: @Lasse, "$myaccount" and "$myrepo" are just name examples. I'm not pushing those text :) . Anyway I solved the problem just a proxy error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka, I found it.
I filled something in Global Settings > Proxy so that I won't need to re-authenticate each time.
This was the cause of the infamous **error SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3** . That was stupid I know.

What I should have done is : 
First uncheck the proxy settings. 

Second I'm too lazy to input my authentication , I should configure paths (Hg Repository Explorer > Synchronize > Configure paths) to save the URL . But still now I don't know how to save my login and pwd . But NOW it **WORKS**

Answer (score 1):

That error is telling you that the path you're trying to push to on bitbitbucket doesn't match the repository you created there.  Perhaps you've got a typo in your username or your project (case matters for both).  The easiest way to get that URL is to copy it right off of the bitbucket page for that repo.

People's confusion in your wording comes from this statement "I want to push (by cloning) my local repo".  Pushing and cloning are separate operations.  Cloning creates a new repository and pushing moves changesets between two already existing repositories.

If you do have a repo locally and remotely already then you want to push but not clone, and you need to get the URL right to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there is no typo. I copied right from the repo .

Comment: Sorry for the wording confusion, I have one local repo and one remote repo (empty that's where I want to push). In the Repository Explorer , I fill the URL and push but I get error SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3 . Something with the login and pwd ? TortoiseHg does't ask them.

Comment: Bitbucket multiplexes both ssh and https on the same port, and for whatever reason it's thinking you're trying to speak ssh.  Try doing the push again with --verbose and please paste in the actual command and messages.